# Working around firewall to install packages

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel

Hi I've been using linux for couple years now but never really sent much time on sysadmin stuff so I sort of know pieces of the answer but I need someone help me fill in the gaps.

I have an EC2 server on AWS that I need to install mongodb on. Usually I can just add mongo repo and `sudo apt-get install mongo-org` etc. but this time the network where my server resides does not allow access to internet.

### What I tried

I have tried to download `mongo-org` onto my client and using `scp` upload onto server, but then server complains about unmet dependencies specifically `libssl1.1`, which is actually installed( I know because I tried installing it myself just to get message that package is up to date).

So now I'm wondering if I can use my client machine to give server temporary internet access, using reverse ssh tunnel. Problem is I knowledge of how ssh works is rusty and my client is a Windows machine with `putty` installed.

So from what I gathered I can open port forwarding on `putty` but going into >Connection>SSH>Tunnels> and add port forward ( I tired `4R7000 localhost:6000').

### Problem 1

I'm really not sure what the next step is I guess in need to give server heads up that there is a tunnel ready? How do I do that?

### Problem 2

Most importantly should I even be doing that or is there a better way to get my packages installed?

### My specs:

#### Client:

Win 10, Putty

#### Server:

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Or ask the administrator of this environment whether they have an internal mirror or a proxy for such purposes.  Working around their security constraints autonomously seems unlikely to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh -D` and set up APT to use a socks proxy to point to the port you speciified:

```
Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks5h://hostname:port/";
```